# BootStrap/ JQuery Call method on page load or render

Tags: jsp, sorting, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to sort a list of programs, with the "checked" or included programs listed first. However, I am having a hard time with bootstrap and getting the method to call when the page loads. This is a .jsp file and utilizing backbone and bootstrap.

Here is my existing function which works fine, but only if the sort button is clicked.

> onSortCheckedClick : function(e) {
>                 e.preventDefault();
>                   var anchor = $(e.currentTarget);

```
            var li = anchor.parent("li.sortChecked");
            if (li.hasClass("active")) {
                return;
            }

            var sortDirectionOrder = anchor.attr("data-direction");
            var sortDirectionColumn = anchor.attr("data-sortByCheck");
            var attributesNames = sortDirectionColumn.split('.');

            var sortedPrograms = this.programs.sortBy(function(program) {
                var answers = program.toJSON();

                var unChecked = new Array();

                var selectAnswers, unselectAnswers;
                if(answers.selected === true){
                    selectAnswers = answers;
                }else if(answers.selected === false){
                    unselectAnswers = answers;
                }

                return unselectAnswers;
            });

            if (sortDirectionOrder === 'asc') {
                sortedPrograms.reverse();
            }

            this.$("thead li.sortChecked").removeClass("active");
            li.addClass("active");
            this.programs.reset(sortedPrograms);
        },
```

And here are the registered event listeners. What would be the best way of going about calling the method above when the list of programs is rendered?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the "list of programs" is a backbone view?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function once your page is rendered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Call your function here
//It is assumed your the list of programs are rendered on page load
//-- Otherwise --
// Call renderProgram() and then call or add event listeners to onSortCheckedClick()
});
```

You can use a jQuery deferred object to handle the call of the onSortCheckedClick after the renderProgram() has been finished.

Call the ready function on main html file (or include it in your main html file).